# Passing parameters to a batch file that end in a numeral

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the requirement to pass an arguments string from one batch file to another for execution at the command line.  Say we have a batch file which takes its arguments (i.e. the command "tail") and creates another batch file that *executes* those arguments.  Consider file Batch1.bat:

```
echo %*>Batch2.bat
call Batch2.bat
```

If we run this with

```
Batch1.bat echo a b c
```

we get

```
a b c
```

which is fine.  But if we run it with

```
Batch1.bat echo 1 2 3
```

we get

```
1 2
```

I guess because the last argument `3` gets interpreted by batch as an operator for the following `>` redirection character.   I know a simple fix would be to add a space, as in

```
echo %* >Batch2.bat
```

but there are occasions when the command line cannot have a trailing space, like:

```
Batch1 set NoEnv=
```

will give you an environment variable with a value of one space character, instead of deleting the environment variable.

So how do I do this? - the requirement is to have a batch file which faithfully executes its command tail (which might include items in quotes, as well as numerals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the redirect to the front of the statement.

```
>batch2.bat echo %*
```

Comment: That looks _so weird!_.  It works though.  Many thanks.